# When i try to update records it will create new record instead of updating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I try to **combine** both **create and edit** file in **one view and controller**. I detect when to edit and when to update by checking id. if **id==0** then it will **create**. But when i updating it will **always create** because the id was **always 0**. But the populated value of the form is correct. Here is my code.

Here is my **Controller:**

```
public IActionResult Upsert(int? id)
{
    if(id == null || id == 0)
    {
        return View();
    }
    Product product = _productRepository.Get(u=>u.Id == id);
    return View(product);
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Upsert(Product product)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (product.Id == 0)
        {
            _productRepository.Add(product);
        }
        else
        {
            _productRepository.Update(product);
        }
        _productRepository.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Here is my **Product Model**:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace test.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? Title { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? ISBN { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string? Author { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Range(1,1000)]
        [Display(Name ="ListPrice")]
        public int ListPrice { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [Range(1, 1000)]
        [Display(Name = "Price for 1-50")]
        public int Price { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(1, 1000)]
        [Display(Name = "Price for 50+")]
        public int Price50 { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(1, 1000)]
        [Display(Name = "Price for 100+")]
        public int Price100 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my **View**:

```
@model Product
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-10">
        <div class="card shadow border-0 mt-4">
            <div class="card-header bg-secondary bg-gradient m-lg-0 py3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 text-center">
                        <h2 class="text-white py-2">Update Category</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body p-4">
                <form method="post" class="row">
                    <input asp-for="Id" hidden value="0" />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-10">
                            <div class="border pt-3">
                                <div class="py-2">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="Title" placeholder="Title" class="form-control form-floating shadow border-0" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="py-2">
                                    <textarea asp-for="Description" placeholder="Discription" class="form-control form-floating shadow border-0"></textarea>

                                </div>
                                <div class="py-2">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="ISBN" placeholder="ISBN" class="form-control form-floating shadow border-0" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="ISBN" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="py-2">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="Author" placeholder="Author" class="form-control form-floating shadow border-0" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Author" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="py-2">
                                    <input type="number" asp-for="ListPrice" placeholder="ListPrice" class="form-control form-floating shadow border-0" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="ListPrice" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="py-2">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="Price" placeholder="Price for 1-50" class="form-control form-floating shadow border-0" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Price" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="py-2">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="Price50" placeholder="Price for 50+" class="form-control form-floating shadow border-0" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Price50" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="py-2">
                                    <input type="text" asp-for="Price100" placeholder="Price for 100+" class="form-control form-floating shadow border-0" />
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Price100" class="text-danger"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row mt-5">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Create</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <a asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-outline-primary form-control">Back to List</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea',
            plugins: 'ai tinycomments mentions anchor autolink charmap codesample emoticons image link lists media searchreplace table visualblocks wordcount checklist mediaembed casechange export formatpainter pageembed permanentpen footnotes advtemplate advtable advcode editimage tableofcontents mergetags powerpaste tinymcespellchecker autocorrect a11ychecker typography inlinecss',
            toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks fontfamily fontsize | bold italic underline strikethrough | link image media table mergetags | align lineheight | tinycomments | checklist numlist bullist indent outdent | emoticons charmap | removeformat',
            tinycomments_mode: 'embedded',
            tinycomments_author: 'Author name',
            mergetags_list: [
                { value: 'First.Name', title: 'First Name' },
                { value: 'Email', title: 'Email' },
            ],
            ai_request: (request, respondWith) => respondWith.string(() => Promise.reject("See docs to implement AI Assistant")),
        });
    </script>
    @{
        <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    }
}
```

I use **repository Pattern** for database.. repository pattern is fine.. because create is working.. also update is working when i try to do with the seperated edit and update file. but i want to combine both here.

Here i am also providing reposiroty...
Here is my repository **interface IRepository**:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace test.dataAccess.Repository.IRepository
{
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter); 
        void Add(T entity);
        void Remove(T entity);
        void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entity);
    }
}
```

And here is the **implementation of IRepository**:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using test.dataAccess.Data;
using test.dataAccess.Repository.IRepository;

namespace test.dataAccess.Repository
{
    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        internal DbSet<T> dbSet;

        public Repository(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
            this.dbSet = _db.Set<T>(); 
        }

        public void Add(T entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = dbSet.Where(filter);
            return query.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = dbSet;
            return query.ToList();
        }

        public void Remove(T entity)
        {
            dbSet.Remove(entity);
        }

        public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entity)
        {
            dbSet.RemoveRange(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the **interface of IProductRepository**:

```
using test.Models;

namespace test.dataAccess.Repository.IRepository
{
    public interface IProductRepository : IRepository<Product>
    {
        void Update(Product product);
        void Save();
    }
}
```

Here is my repository **interface IRepository**:

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace test.dataAccess.Repository.IRepository
{
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter); 
        void Add(T entity);
        void Remove(T entity);
        void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entity);
    }
}
```

And the implementation of **IProductRepository**:

```
using test.dataAccess.Data;
using test.dataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using test.Models;

namespace test.dataAccess.Repository
{
    public class ProductRepository : Repository<Product>, IProductRepository
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public ProductRepository(ApplicationDbContext db) : base(db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Update(Product product)
        {
            _db.Update(product);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to **combine both edit** and create page. **create is working **but when i try to update data it will create instead of **update**. when i debug i found that the id value is always **zero** when the **post** method is called. so it will create instead of update

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to find why Id values are always 0, should it?

Comment: "But the populated value of the form is correct ". I guess the form is not sending always 0 on id, right ?

Comment: See this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613044/asp-net-mvc-3-save-and-edit-from-the-same-form

Comment: @EduardoFellipe form is always sending id==0 .. always creating new record

Comment: @GertArnold i dont know ... I couldn't find.. i am new to dot net .. learning ... Dont know much .. with my knowledge i could find

Answer (score 1):

```
   public void Update(Product product)
    {
          _db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

You may also need to attach the product to the context in order to let it be tracked. so use this line, before changing the State, when needed

```
 _db.Attach(product);
```

also notice that `<input asp-for="Id" hidden value="0" />` will always override the real value from the model id even in `update` mode. remove the `value="0"`.

here is the correct input field

```
   <input asp-for="Id" type="hidden" />
```

Comment: i don't understand where to add which ... i am new to dotnet learning .. please tell me a littile bit specific where to add wchich line.

Comment: in your Update method, instead of `_db.Update(product);`  use  `_db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: no.. it did not work...still create instead of update

Answer (score 0):

Because you always bind the id value to 0 .`<input asp-for="Id" hidden value="0" />`.
On your description you should change it to  `<input type="text" asp-for="Id" placeholder="Id"` to let the id bind to original model value , then you could change the value to 0 if you want to create. And leave the value what it should be when you want to update.
But still, it is a wired design. In my opinion, there should be two button "create " "update" to submit to form to different action.

```
<form>
    <input asp-for="Id"/>
    ...
    <button asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Create" formmethod="post">Create</button>
    <button asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Update" formmethod="post">Update</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks.. i can done with the different controller .. but i want to do it with the same controller and same view. i can separate with the id .. if id is zero .. then it will create because there will be no id to get.. and othe case it will update .